# XIX century Russian math prodigies who published in Crelle

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, 19th-century, russia

I recall there being two Russian math prodigies who published a joint paper in the Crelle's journal at the age of 18 or so. I think they lived in the XIX century. What were their names?

I can't remember and my description may be a little off.

Comment: Could they be the Markov Brothers, and the joint paper be on the [Markov brothers Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality).  The younger brother [Vladimir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Markov_(mathematician)) died tragically at the age of 25.

Comment: @Nick I remembered. It was Friedmann and Tamarkin.

Comment: Ah!  For some reason I thought I had read "brothers" in your question, but re-reading this is not the case.